# Hibernate many-to-many produces null member

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I have two entity classes with many-to-many relation on there fields.
Here they are:

```
public class TCustomerProfile {
...
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE},mappedBy = "customers")
private List<TUserProfile> users;
...
}
public class TUserProfile{
...
@JoinTable(name = "T_USER_AUTHORIZATION", 
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID" ,referencedColumnName ="USER_ID")/*,@JoinColumn(name = "ENTITY1" ,referencedColumnName ="ENTITY")*/ }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_ID" ,referencedColumnName ="CUSTOMER_ID")/*,@JoinColumn(name = "ENTITY" ,referencedColumnName ="ENTITY")*/} )
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<TCustomerProfile> customers;
...
}
```

**Now the question:**
How is it possible that one of the users in the `TCustomerProfile.users` is `null`?
Is it some data combination in the three tables (including the `join table t_user_authorization`) that results in this?

Comment: Stupid test: does anything change when you remove the eager loading?

Comment: I cannot really debug this since the data is on customer's site. That is why I am asking this question - to know what to look for in the data.

Comment: I don't see what data has to do with being able to change a hibernate mapping parameter. I'd at least try to stay involved in the process of figuring it out instead of posting the question and waiting for an answer, the question itself is too shallow to be able to answer without further investigation and code.

Comment: FWIW I'm having this problem with a relation without Fetch=EAGER in an old project with Hibernate 4.3.11.